# Array undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello my problem is that i get undefined , when trying to accsess the array length, but everything works fine when i try to access only the array.

this above do not works ->

```
console.log(this.ref_number_response[0].info.length);
```

This works ->

```
console.log(this.ref_number_response);
```

and this is the whole

```
check_ref_number: function () {

 this.ref_number_response = [];

 axios.get('/is_referenceNumber_free/'+this.ref_number)
 .then(response => this.ref_number_response.push({ 
   info: response.data

}));


 console.log(this.ref_number_response[0].info.length);

 Event.$emit('reference_added', this.ref_number_response);

},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You should check what `ref_number_response` contains and type.

Comment: You need to put that code inside your `then` statement.

Comment: I have not received any solution...

Answer (score 0):

Emit the event after you recieve the data:

```
check_ref_number: function () {
 axios.get('/is_referenceNumber_free/'+this.ref_number)
 .then(response => Event.$emit('reference_added',[{info:response.data}]));
}
```

The problem is that you are getting the data asynchronously, and trying to use the data before it is ready.

Comment: what error are you getting? add a catch clause and print the error.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are trying to access **the the array length**, but

```
this.ref_number_response
```

is the array, so the only way this `console.log(this.ref_number_response[0].info.length);` is  going to work ( you're trying to get the info property from first element of the array length not the actual array length ) is if info were an array as well. So you'd probably need to do something like:

```
console.log(this.ref_number_response.length);
```

Comment: While this is true, the code provided above will still fail regardless of this change.

Comment: what error do you get after the changes? undefined? null value? ( note that the guy above is also right  )

Comment: This does not work, I have expose the right way to the length but I am missing something else